# Fastest way to delete and return last n items from an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have an array in JavaScript, how can I remove the last n items from it and return it as a new array?

I have two options, splice or to iterate pops/pushes. Which is better?

Thanks

Comment: splice should be better … almost always, what is implemented natively already will beat anything that you implement yourself in a loop.

Comment: Why do you care about the fastest way? Use the simplest way (which is `splice`).

Comment: faster and simpler, the splice of life, can't beat it with a stick.

Comment: You can use http://jsperf.com/ to test performance of each method.

Answer (score 5):

You should splice it:

```
array.splice(array.length-n, array.length);
```

As such:

```js
function removeLast(arr, n){
    arr.splice(arr.length-n, arr.length);
    return arr;
}
arr = JSON.parse(prompt("Enter the array"));
n = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of elements you want to remove"), 10);
alert(removeLast(arr, n));
```

---

```
> removeLast([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
[1, 2]
> removeLast([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
[1, 2, 3]
> removeLast([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I whipped up a quick jsperf test to compare the two methods

http://jsperf.com/splicevspop

Splice is demonstrably faster